# JWT Authentication with NextJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt

I've searched around a bit, but have not found any clear, up-to-date, answers on this topic.

I'm trying to implement JWT authentication in my NextJS application. The following is what I have so far.

- `/login` endpoint that will (1) check that the user/pass exists and is valid, and (2) create a JWT token based on a private RS256 key.
- Created a middleware layer to verify the JWT

The creation of the JWT is fine - it works perfectly well reading the key from the file-system and signing a JWT.

However, I've run into the problem of the middleware being unable to use node modules (`fs` and `path`) because of the edge runtime (read [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime#unsupported-apis)). This makes it so I'm unable to read the public key from the FS.

What is the proper way to verify a JWT token on every request? I've read that `fetch`ing from middleware is bad practice and should be avoided. All other reference on this topic (that I found) either uses a "secret" instead of a key (and can therefor be put into `process.env` and used in middleware) or glosses over the fact ([1](https://github.com/lbke/research/blob/main/auth.md#how-to-verify-the-token)). Or should I just create a separate express application to handle JWT creation/verifying?

Answer (score 2):

If you signed the token from

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
```

then you can use same `jwt` for verifying token inside a middleware function. you create `_middleware.js` inside `pages` directory and middleware will run for each request before request hits the endpoint:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export async function middleware(req, ev) {
  
  const token = req ? req.cookies?.token : null;

  let userId=null;
   if (token) {
     // this is how we sign= jwt.sign(object,secretKey)
     // now use the same secretKey to decode the token
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    userId = decodedToken?.issuer;
  }
   
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  // if user sends request to "/api/login", it has no token. so let the request pass
  if (
    pathname.includes("/api/login") || userId
  ) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (!token && pathname !== "/login") {
    return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
  }
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this does not work since it throws an edge runtime error when you use `jwt.verify`

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add a file (`_middleware.tsx`) within `pages`. This ensures the file runs each page load but is not treated as a standard page. In this file lives an Edge function. If the user is not signed in (no `JWT` in cookies) and tries to access a protected page, he is immediately redirected to `/signin` *before the server is even hit*.

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const signedInPages = ["/admin", "/members "];

export default function middleware(req) {
  if (signedInPages.find((p) => p === req.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    const { MY_TOKEN: token } = req.cookies;

    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect("/signin");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do exactly this already, but is there a way to verify the token in the middleware function? The edge API prevents certain Node modules from running (such as FS, path, etc). What is the proper way to verify?

Answer (score -1):

you send the token in the post request header.

```
{Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token}
```

And then verify that token on the server, before sending data back

To verify the token you create a middleware function, then use that function on any route you want to portect

```
router.get("/", middlewarefunction, function (req: any, res: any, next: any) {
  res.send("/api")
})
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I can already access the token server-side via (request) cookies. My question is _how_ to verify that token on the server.